# Flask - добавление других шрифтов

Tags: html, flask

Задал в `.css` дополнительные шрифты. Пути все правильные, ибо `flask` их видит. При загрузки страницы, эти шрифты не отображаются. Firefox пишет следующую ошибку:

```
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Montserrat-Regular" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: http://192.168.0.101/static/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf
```

мой `.css`

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Montserrat-Regular';
src: url(../static/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf) format('truetype'); }
```

Comment: это защита Firefox, посмотрите, например, здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723402/css-font-family-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: @titov_andrei шрифты не отображаются на всех браузерах

Comment: @titov_andrei притом что, если запускаю этот сайт через локалку, все работает. Если же через Raspberry Pi Flask, то получаю эту ошибку

Comment: Проблему нашел, файлы неправильно были скопированы несколько раз и не имели размера и информации.